# Mongoose string schema property with a unique constraint

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

If you have the following schema in Mongoose, how does it affect the collection?

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";

export interface IString {
  property: string;
}

export const PriceOverhaulSchema = new Schema<IString>({
  property: { type: String, required: false, unique: true },
});
```

My question is about the behavior of the unique constraint in this schema. If I have a single document that doesn't have the property field set, can I have another document without violating the uniqueness constraint? In other words, does the uniqueness constraint apply only to documents with the property set, or is it enforced regardless of whether or not the property is set?

I appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you add the `required: true, unique: true` properties to a field on a new schema and then create the first document in the collection, mongoose will add a unique index to the collection for you, which will enforce uniqueness.

However, if you add the `required: false, unique: true` properties to a new schema and then create the first document mongoose won't create the unique index until you create a document which has that field included.

This a mute point though, because once you have that index established as soon as you create a document without that field included mongoose will add a null value in it's place.

This means if you create another document and don't include that field, mongoose will throw the `E11000 duplicate key error`. Simply because you already have a document with a null value so uniqueness is enforced!

That suggests there really is no point in making it `required: false` when `unique: true`.

Comment: @Shocky2 you're welcome.